# What are the options for inter application (non HTTP based). notification systems

Tags: notifications, websub

Does there exist anything similar to Pubsubhubbub for communicating between non HTTP servers (Thrift servers). 
PubsubHubbub with HTTP and RSS is an over kill for my current setup.

Are there any existing solutions / approaches which try to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft OS, you can use MSMQ

Comment: Thanks, But I am on Linux and it would be better if the solution was cross platform.